# How to create a dropdown menu using javascript in bluebeam to auto populate a text box

Tags: javascript

Apologies as I do not have any JavaScript experience. I am looking at creating a stamp for submittals in Bluebeam. I downloaded one of the templates from Bluebeam website which I was able to customize the Javascript for the text fields and radio group. I am looking to create an interactive stamp in Bluebeam.

The last part of the stamp is the description/note that would go along with the "reviewed", "reviewed as noted", or "revise and resubmit" selections. I am looking to select one of those three options in the JavaScript window and based on my selection have it auto populate one of three pre determined descriptions that go along with the selection.

I initially started with a dropdown form on the bluebeam stamp and was trying to have that show up as a dropdown option in the javascript pop up window when I add the stamp to a document in Bluebeam. The issue with this option as you'll see in the image below is that the drop down ends up as single line text which gets cut off. Problem is I'm not sure how to work out the script to allow either of these options to happen. Worst case I would just create 3 different stamps but would like to avoid this if I could.

See images of the current stamp + current script + current interactive javascript window and what I'd like to achieve.

[image: stamp template]

[image: Current Script]

[image: Stamp Dialog JavaScript Window]

[image: Stamp]

Answer (score 0):

add a pop group and popup items in the stampcode script. if you want to have same as dropdown in the dialog when you apply the stamp.
[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwpzW.png)

[SCRIPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SIJg.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30858353)